# Extension function and tail call optimization (TCO) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, tail-recursion

I have the following function that uses TCO:

```
tailrec fun superDigit(n: String): Int {
    val sum = n.fold(0) { sum, char -> sum + char.toString().toInt() }
    return if (sum < 10) sum else superDigit(sum.toString())
}
```

If I implement the same function as an extension function like this:

```
fun String.superDigit(): Int {
    val sum = fold(0) { sum, char -> sum + char.toString().toInt() }
    return if (sum < 10) sum else sum.toString().superDigit()
}
```

Is the extension function tail call optimized as well?

IMO calling the extension function is still a regular function call with `this` as parameter so it's still a recursive call and since tailrec can't be used in extension functions, my assumption is that it's not been optimized by the compiler. Is this assumption correct or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since tailrec can't be used in extension functions

Are you sure?

I've just tested it by taking a look at Kotlin bytecode in IntelliJ IDEA. First of all, the code with `tailrec` on the extension function compiles successfully. Going further: compare the two pieces of Kotlin code and bytecode below, one with `tailrec`, and the other one without.

Kotlin:

```
fun Double.tailrecTestExtension(): Double
        = (this - 1.0).tailrecTestExtension()
```

Bytecode:

```
  // access flags 0x19
  public final static tailrecTestExtension(D)D
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
   L0
    LINENUMBER 13 L0
    DLOAD 0
    DCONST_1
    DSUB
    INVOKESTATIC com/example/TestKt.tailrecTestExtension (D)D
    DRETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE $receiver D L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 4
    MAXLOCALS = 2
```

Kotlin:

```
tailrec fun Double.tailrecTestExtension(): Double
        = (this - 1.0).tailrecTestExtension()
```

Bytecode:

```
  // access flags 0x19
  public final static tailrecTestExtension(D)D
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
   L0
    LINENUMBER 13 L0
    DLOAD 0
    DCONST_1
    DSUB
    DSTORE 0
    GOTO L0
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE $receiver D L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 4
    MAXLOCALS = 2
```

Notice that in the first example there's `INVOKESTATIC` call (which corresponds to a regular recursion), which was replaced with a regular jump (`GOTO`) in the second version (which corresponds to a loop - expected behavior introduced by `tailrec`).

Note: I'm not an expert in Kotlin bytecode, my understanding is based on some basic knowledge about the assembly language. Here I assume that this knowledge is transferable to Kotlin bytecode.

Comment: Yes indeed, it looks like the function call has been replaced by a simple loop without recursion so my assumption that extension functions can't do tail call optimization is wrong. Thanks for digging into the byte code.